# Invoking epics from within other epics

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

First of all many props for this awesome library! I am still struggling with an use case though. I would like to call another epic first and wait till it completes before continuing the current epic. Let's say I have a form where an user can change things. Before loading other data into the form, I want to save the current changes first. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you want: if one epic would like to kick off another epics work and 
wait for it to complete before proceeding.

One approach is (using pseudo names), when receiving the initial action `LOAD_OTHER_DATA` you immediately start listening for a single `SAVE_FORM_FULFILLED`, which signals that the form has been saved (we'll kick it off in a bit). When received, we `mergeMap` (or `switchMap`, doesn't matter in this case) that into our call to load the other data `loadOtherDataSomehow()` and do the usual business. Finally, the trick to kick off the actual saving of the form we're waiting for is adding a `startWith()` at the end of that entire chain--which will emit and dispatch the action to actually save the form.

```js
const saveFormEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType('SAVE_FORM')
    .switchMap(() =>
      saveFormSomeHow(store.getState().formDataSomewhere)
        .map(details => ({
          type: 'SAVE_FORM_FULFILLED'
        }))
    );

const loadOtherDataEpic = action$ =>
  action$
    .ofType('LOAD_OTHER_DATA')
    .switchMap(() =>
      action$.ofType('SAVE_FORM_FULFILLED')
        .take(1) // don't listen forever! IMPORTANT!
        .mergeMap(() =>
          loadOtherDataSomeHow()
            .map(otherData => ({
              type: 'LOAD_OTHER_DATA_FULFILLED',
              payload: otherData
            }))
        )
        .startWith({
          type: 'SAVE_FORM'
        })
    );
```

You didn't mention how your loading and saving works, so this is just pseudo code that you'll need to amend for your use case.

Comment: wow thanks for the thorough answer! Can I have one small additional question on top of this? The saving is optional as in "when the user did not saved it by himself I would like the epic to do it for the him". So I looked at the Observer.if() method and looks like that will fit, but I can't figure out to do it optionally in the "loadOtherDataEpc".

Comment: Just use a simple if/else conditional

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks again for the thorough answer!

Comment: @robinvdvleuten you're welcome! please accept this answer when you get a chance :)

Answer (score 1):

@jayphelps, I just wanted to say thank you for the all questions you have answered, they have really helped me solve many of my problems.

I was trying to formulate my question and found that you had already answered it here and managed to use your sample to fix my problem.

My example has/had 2 expics that I want/ed to call after each other:

```
const requestNameEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType("REQUEST_NAME")
    .switchMap(({id}) =>
      Observable.of(`name returned by 'ajax' call, using id: ${id}`) // Ajax simulation
        .delay(1000)
        .map(name => ({type: "LOAD_NAME", name}))
    );

const requestAgeEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType("REQUEST_AGE")
    .switchMap(({name}) =>
      Observable.of(`age returned by 'ajax' call, using name: [${name}]`)
        .delay(1000)
        .map(age => ({type: "LOAD_AGE", age}))
    );
```

The way I managed to solve it was using:

```
const requestDetailsEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType("LOAD_NAME")
    .map(({name}) => ({type: "REQUEST_AGE", name}));
```

So dispatching REQUEST_NAME would also dispatch REQUEST_AGE, but then I would never be able to only dispatch LOAD_NAME.

I refactored your sample to get:

```
const requestDetailsEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType("REQUEST_DETAILS")
    .switchMap(({id}) =>
      action$.ofType("LOAD_NAME")
        .take(1) // don't listen forever! IMPORTANT!
        .map(({name}) => ({type: "REQUEST_AGE", name}))
        .startWith({type: "REQUEST_NAME", id})
  );
```

Thank you again for all the great work you do on redux-observable and all the community support.