# Chained redux-observable epic only fires correctly once

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I've set up an epic that waits for another epic to complete, much like @jayphelps' answer here: [Invoking epics from within other epics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276419/invoking-epics-from-within-other-epics)

However I've found that it only seems to run once. After that I can see the `CART_CONFIG_READY` action in the console but the `DO_THE_NEXT_THING` action is not triggered.

I've tried various combinations of `mergeMap` and `switchMap`, with and without `take` but nothing seems to help.

This is (kind of) what my code looks like.

```js
import { NgRedux } from '@angular-redux/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ActionsObservable } from 'redux-observable';

export class CartEpicsService {

checkCart = (action$: ActionsObservable<any>, store: NgRedux<any>) => {

    return action$.ofType('CHECK_CART')
        .switchMap(() => {

            console.log('___LISTENING___');

            return action$.ofType('CART_CONFIG_READY')
                .take(1) // removing this doesn't help
                .mergeMap(() => {

                    console.log('___RECEIVED___');

                    // do stuff here

                    return Observable.of({
                        type: 'DO_THE_NEXT_THING'
                    });

                })
                .startWith({
                    type: 'GET_CART_CONFIG'
                });

        });

}

getCartConfig = (action$: ActionsObservable<any>, store: NgRedux<any>) => {

    return action$.ofType('GET_CART_CONFIG')
        .switchMap(() => {

            const config = store.getState().config;

            // we already have the config
            if (config) {
                return Observable.of({
                    type: 'CART_CONFIG_READY'
                });
            }

            // otherwise load it from the server using out HTTP service
            return this.http.get('/cart/config')
                .switchMap((response) => {
                    return Observable.concat(
                        Observable.of({
                            type: 'CART_CONFIG_SUCCESS'
                        }),
                        Observable.of({
                            type: 'CART_CONFIG_READY'
                        })
                    );
                })
                .catch(error => Observable.of({
                    type: 'CART_CONFIG_ERROR',
                    error
                }));


        });

    }

}
```

For context I need the response from the /cart/config endpoint to check the validity of the cart. I only need to download the config once.

Here is a runnable example on JS Bin:

https://jsbin.com/vovejibuwi/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dang this is definitely a tricky one!

## Cause

When `state.config === true` you return an Observable of `CART_CONFIG_READY` that emits synchronously, whereas during the first time the http request (or delay, in the jsbin) means it is always going to be async.

Why this makes a difference is in the `checkCart` epic you return an observable chain that listens for `CART_CONFIG_READY` with `action$.ofType('CART_CONFIG_READY')` but also applies a `.startWith({ type: 'GET_CART_CONFIG' })`. That means that `GET_CART_CONFIG` is going to be emitted synconously **before** `action$.ofType('CART_CONFIG_READY')` is subscribed because `startWith` is [basically shorthand for a concat](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operators/startWith.ts#L44-L49), which might would make the issue more clear if you're familiar with it. It's nearly exactly the same as doing this:

```
Observable.concat(
  Observable.of({
    type: 'GET_CART_CONFIG'
  }),
  action$.ofType('CART_CONFIG_READY') // not subscribed until prior complete()s
    .take(1)
    .mergeMap(() => {
      // stuff
    })
);
```

So to summarize, what is happening the second time around `GET_CART_CONFIG` is dispatched synchronously, `getCartConfig` receives it and sees the config is already in the store so it synchronously dispatches `CART_CONFIG_READY`. But we are not yet listening for it in `checkCart` so it goes unanswered. Then that callstack returns and the next Observable in the concat, our `action$.ofType('CART_CONFIG_READY')` chain, gets subscribed to. But too late, the action it listens for has already been emitted!

## Solutions

One way to fix this is to make either the emitting of `CART_CONFIG_READY` always async, or to start listening for it in the other epic *before* we dispatch `GET_CART_CONFIG`.

#### 1. emit CART_CONFIG_READY async

`Observable.of` accepts a scheduler as its last argument, and [RxJS supports several of them](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#scheduler).

In this case you could use the `AsyncScheduler` (macrotask) or the `AsapScheduler` (microtask). Both will work in this case, but they schedule on different times in the JavaScript event loop. If you're not familiar with event loop tasks, [check this out](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/).

I would personally recommend using the `AsyncSheduler` in this case because it will provide the closest async behavior to making an http request.

```
import { async } from 'rxjs/scheduler/async';

// later inside your epic...

return Observable.of({
  type: 'CART_CONFIG_READY'
}, async);
```

#### 2. Listen for `CART_CONFIG_READY` before emitting `GET_CART_CONFIG`

Because `startWith` is shorthand for a `concat` (which we don't want to do) we instead need to use some form of `merge`, with our `ofType` chain first so that we listen before emitting.

```
action$.ofType('CART_CONFIG_READY')
  .take(1)
  .mergeMap(() => {
    // stuff
  })
  .merge(
    Observable.of({ type: 'GET_CART_CONFIG' })
  )

// or

Observable.merge(
  action$.ofType('CART_CONFIG_READY')
    .take(1)
    .mergeMap(() => {
      // stuff
    }),
  Observable.of({ type: 'GET_CART_CONFIG' })
)

// both are exactly the same, pick personal preference on appearance
```

You only need to do one of these solutions, but it wouldn't hurt to do both of them. Offhand I would probably recommend using both just so that things are consistent and expected, even if they are a bit more verbose.

---

You might also be happy to know that `Observable.of` accepts any number of items, which will be emitted in order. So you don't need to use `concat`:

```
// before

Observable.concat(
  Observable.of({
    type: 'CART_CONFIG_SUCCESS'
  }),
  Observable.of({
    type: 'CART_CONFIG_READY'
  })
)

// after

Observable.of({
  type: 'CART_CONFIG_SUCCESS'
}, {
  type: 'CART_CONFIG_READY'
})
```

Thanks so much for the jsbin btw, it made it **much** easier to debug.

---

Edit based on your comment:

> Out of curiosity did you figure this out through experience or debugging?

A combination of both. I've dealt with a ton of async/scheduled code and ordering is very commonly the source of issues. I scanned the code, mentally picturing execution, noticed the difference in async vs sync depending on codepath, then I made a quick operator to make it easy for me to confirm the order in which any Observable chain is subscribed to.

```
Observable.prototype.logOnSubscribe = function (msg) {
  // defer is a pretty useful Observable to learn if you haven't yet
  return Observable.defer(() => {
    console.log(msg);
    return this; // the original source
  });
};
```

I applied it to several places, but the most important are these two:

```
action$.ofType('CART_CONFIG_READY')
  .take(1)
  .mergeMap(() => {
    // stuff
  })
  .logOnSubscribe('listening for CART_CONFIG_READY') // <--- here
  .startWith({
    type: 'GET_CART_CONFIG'
  });

  //  and in the other epic...

  if (hasConfig) {
    return Observable.of({
      type: 'CART_CONFIG_READY'
    })
    .logOnSubscribe('emitting CART_CONFIG_READY');  // <--- and here
  }
```

It confirmed that in the second code path `CART_CONFIG_READY` was getting emitted before the other epic was listening for it.

Comment: Wow! Thank you Jay! Out of curiosity did you figure this out through experience or debugging?

Comment: @DanielCrisp you're welcome! I added my reply as an amendment to the end of my answer.

Comment: I'm not aware of defer... so much to learn! Saving that snippet - that is a great little trick. The internals of Rx are a bit of a mystery to me still, I think it is time to get studying :-) Thanks again and good work with redux-observable.