# rxjs - How to retry after catching and processing an error with emitting something

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm using rxjs `v5.4.3`, redux-observable `v0.16.0`.

in my application, I'd like to achieve below:

- an user has auth token, and refresh token to regenerate auth token.
- the user requests with auth token. (by emitting REQUEST action)
- if it failed, request regenerating auth token with refresh token.

  - if refreshed, emit TOKEN_REFRESHED action to update auth token, and do not emit REQUEST_FAILURE.
  - if refreshing failed, emit REQUEST_FAILURE
- after refreshing(and updating auth token reducer), retry requesting using the refreshed auth token.

  - if request succeeded, emit REQUEST_SUCCESS, and if failed, emit REQUEST_FAILURE.

I'd like to achieve like:

```
const fetchEpic = (action$: ActionsObservable<Action>, store: Store<IRootState>) => action$
  .ofAction(actions.fetchPost)
  .mergeMap(({ payload: { postId } })) => {
    const { authToken, refreshToken } = store.getState().auth;

    return api.fetchPost({ postId, authToken }) // this returns Observable<ResponseJSON>
      .map(res => actions.fetchSuccess({ res })) // if success, just emit success-action with the response
      .catch(err => {
        if (isAuthTokenExpiredError(err) {
          return api.reAuthenticate({ refreshToken })
            .map(res => actions.refreshTokenSuccess({ authToken: res.authToken });
            .catch(actions.fetchFailure({ err }))
            // and retry fetchPost after re-authenticate!
        }

        return Observable.of(actions.fetchFailure({ err }))
      })
  }
```

is there any solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling refresh tokens using rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907151/handling-refresh-tokens-using-rxjs)

Comment: This looks pretty similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907151/handling-refresh-tokens-using-rxjs  Basically you want to `flatMap` the original request into something that returns the response or a retried attempt.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I read the question, but I think the situation is different from here.

It seems that the way introduced in the question is to just refresh and retry. but I want to do is not only to do so but also to emit the value for Redux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, but I would recommend splitting off the reauthentication into its own epic to make it easier to maintain/test/reuse.

Here's what that might look like:

```
const reAuthenticateEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$.ofType(actions.reAuthenticate)
    .switchMap(() => {
      const { refreshToken } = store.getState().auth;

      return api.reAuthenticate({ refreshToken })
        .map(res => actions.refreshTokenSuccess({ authToken: res.authToken }))
        .catch(err => Observable.of(
          actions.refreshTokenFailure({ err })
        ));
    });
```

We'll also want to use something like `Observable.defer` so that each time we retry, we look up the **latest** version of the `authToken`:

```
Observable.defer(() => {
  const { authToken } = store.getState().auth;
    return api.fetchPost({ postId, authToken });
})
```

When we catch errors in `fetchEpic` and detect `isAuthTokenExpiredError` we return an Observable chain that:

1. Starts listening for a single `refreshTokenSuccess`, signalling we can retry
2. Just in case the reauthing itself fails, we listen for it with `.takeUntil(action$.ofType(refreshTokenFailure))` so that we aren't waiting around forever--you might want to handle this case differently, your call.
3. mergeMap it to the original source, which is the second argument of the `catch` callback. The "source" is the Observable chain before the `catch`, and since Observables are lazy, when we receive the `refreshTokenSuccess` action it it will resubscribe to that chain again, effectively be a "retrying"
4. Merge the above chain with an Observable of an `reAuthenticate` action. This is used to kick off the actual reauth.

To summarize: the Observable chain we return from `catch` will first starting listening for `refreshTokenSuccess`, then it emits `reAuthenticate`, then when (and if) we receive `refreshTokenSuccess` we will then "retry" the source, our `api.fetchPost()` chain above the `catch` that we wrapped in an `Observable.defer`. If `refreshTokenFailure` is emitted before we receive our `refreshTokenSuccess`, we give up entirely.

```
const fetchEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$.ofType(actions.fetchPost)
    .mergeMap(({ payload: { postId } })) =>
      Observable.defer(() => {
        const { authToken } = store.getState().auth;
        return api.fetchPost({ postId, authToken });
      })
        .map(res => actions.fetchSuccess({ res }))
        .catch((err, source) => {
          if (isAuthTokenExpiredError(err)) {
            // Start listening for refreshTokenSuccess, then kick off the reauth
            return action$.ofType(actions.refreshTokenSuccess)
              .takeUntil(action$.ofType(refreshTokenFailure))
              .take(1)
              .mergeMapTo(source) // same as .mergeMap(() => source)
              .merge(
                Observable.of(action.reAuthenticate())
              );
          } else {
            return Observable.of(actions.fetchFailure({ err }));
          }
        });
    );
```

These examples are untested, so I may have some minor issues but you hopefully get the gist. There's also probably a more elegant way to do this, but this will at least unblock you. (Others are more than welcome to edit this answer if they can decrease the complexity)

---

#### Side notes

- This creates the slight potential for infinite retries, which can cause nasty issues both in the person's browser or your servers. It might be a good idea to only retry a set number of times, and/or put some sort of delay in between your retries. In practice this might not be worth worrying about, you'll know best.
- You (or someone else reading this later) may be tempted to use `.startWith(action.reAuthenticate())` instead of the merge, but be mindful that a `startWith` is just shorthand for a `concat`, not a `merge`, which means it would synchronously emit the action before we have started to listen for a success one. Usually that isn't an issue since http requests are async, but [it's caused people bugs before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46455271/1770633).

Comment: thanks for your very detailed answer. 

it is great, but I faced a problem. this way seems request with same authToken even though refreshTokenSuccess emitted and authToken in reducer is updated. I cannot think of any way to change the attribute of `fetchPost`..

Comment: @tsugitta ah yes, that makes sense. I edited the code in my example to wrap the `api.fetchPost` stuff in an `Observable.defer` which means each time it's subscribed to it will get the latest state.

Comment: @tsugitta you're welcome! I edited my answer slightly for posterity, just to cover the defer stuff. It's also likely there is a less complex way to do all of this. If you improve this later, I'd love to see it so please ping me and edit my answer!